# extract xml tag based on max xpath of list value

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath

I'm attempting to extract a currency value from an xml list, which is at the same level as the maximum value of another tag (within the same list).

I am using Oracle SQL 11gR2.
The maximum value extract is based on the xpath max() function.
I've then attempted to subscript the list (for currency tag) based on the result of the max(), but the currency appears as NULL.
This is a small sample of the data, and the associated xpath's used:

```
with xml_data as (    
select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
  <SOME_OBJECT xmlns="http://www.example.com/xxyy/">    
    <ILA>    
      <PRODUCT_LIST>    
        <PRODUCT>    
          <MAP_ENTRY>  
            <CURRENCY_ENTRY>EUR</CURRENCY_ENTRY>  
          </MAP_ENTRY>  
          <INITIAL_VALUE>1.4219777502E8</INITIAL_VALUE>    
        </PRODUCT>    
        <PRODUCT>  
          <MAP_ENTRY>  
            <CURRENCY_ENTRY>ZAR</CURRENCY_ENTRY>  
          </MAP_ENTRY>  
          <INITIAL_VALUE>1.4612991655E8</INITIAL_VALUE>  
        </PRODUCT>    
        <PRODUCT>  
          <MAP_ENTRY>  
            <CURRENCY_ENTRY>USD</CURRENCY_ENTRY>  
          </MAP_ENTRY>  
          <INITIAL_VALUE>1.4712991655E8</INITIAL_VALUE>    
        </PRODUCT>    
      </PRODUCT_LIST>    
    </ILA>    
  </SOME_OBJECT>') as msg from dual union all    
  select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
  <SOME_OBJECT xmlns="http://www.example.com/xxyy/">    
    <ILA>    
       <SUBSEQUENT_VALUE>10266</SUBSEQUENT_VALUE>    
    </ILA>    
  </SOME_OBJECT>') as msg from dual    
)    
--    
select x.subsequent_value, x.max_initial_value ,x.currency   
from xml_data d  
    ,xmltable (xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.example.com/xxyy/')    
              ,'/SOME_OBJECT'  passing d.msg    
              columns    
                   max_initial_value number path 'max(ILA/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE)'  
                  ,currency varchar2(3) path 'ILA/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT[INITIAL_VALUE=max(ILA/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE)]/MAP_ENTRY/CURRENCY_ENTRY'  
                  ,subsequent_value number path 'ILA/SUBSEQUENT_VALUE'    
             ) as x;
```

So the existing output is:

```
SQL> @get_max

SUBSEQUENT_VALUE MAX_INITIAL_VALUE CUR
---------------- ----------------- ---
                 147129917
       10266
```

The first line should include USD.
Any suggestions as to what the xpath should be ?

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath looks fine to me in theory, 
im not an expert but there might be a problem here :

your displayed value of MAX_INITIAL_VALUE is 147129917 so it has been rounded right ?
Therefore, it cannot be equal to the actual value of 1.4712991655E8 in your XML object

maybe if there is a round function :

```
currency varchar2(3) path 'ILA/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT[INITIAL_VALUE=round(max(ILA/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE))]/MAP_ENTRY/CURRENCY_ENTRY'
```

it would probably take a second argument for which decimal to round at if it exists

Answer (score 0):

The full path has to be specified for the max() function, as follows:
`ILA/TION/PAWS/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT[INITIAL_VALUE = max(/SOME_OBJECT/ILA/TION/PAWS/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE)]/MAP_ENTRY/CURRENCY_ENTRY'`

Using the same data from the original post, with a modified SQL statement, that includes the full path shows up the currency:

```
select x.subsequent_value, x.max_initial_value ,x.currency     
from xml_data d    
    ,xmltable (xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.example.com/xxyy/')      
              ,'/SOME_OBJECT'  passing d.msg      
              columns      
                  p XMLTYPE PATH '.'  
                  ,  max_initial_value number path 'max(ILA/TION/PAWS/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE)'    
                  , currency varchar2(3) path 'ILA/TION/PAWS/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT[INITIAL_VALUE = max(/SOME_OBJECT/ILA/TION/PAWS/PRODUCT_LIST/PRODUCT/INITIAL_VALUE)]/MAP_ENTRY/CURRENCY_ENTRY'    
                  , subsequent_value number path 'ILA/TION/PAWS/SUBSEQUENT_VALUE'      
             ) as x; 

SUBSEQUENT_VALUE MAX_INITIAL_VALUE CURRENCY

---------------- ----------------- --------

                         147129917 USD    

           10266
```

Alternatively, playing around with virtual paths might also do the trick, but it will slow down your query.